# Bundler failing to install gems: i18n gem v 0.6.10 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-i18n

I have run into an issue when trying to push my rails 4 app to heroku. It fails to install gems via bundler and says that it cannot find i18n .6.10

It seems the current version of i18n is .6.9.

I uninstalled gem i18n and reinstalled. On installation, it says that it installed .9 but when I do bundle show i18n, it shows version 10.

I have never seen a problem with i18n or any of the gem file.lock gems before. How do i force it to use 9?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.6.10` [was yanked recently](http://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/versions). You should see which gem depends on a yanked version of `i18n` by inspecting your `Gemfile.lock`. Also, try to specify version of `i18n` explicitly in `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'i18n', '0.6.9'
```

And run `bundle update`.